# Scheduling Notifications with broadcast reciever and actions on click

Tags: android, android-notifications

I am new to android and currently learning about notifications, there's a small app I am making which is supposed to show notification later in time and should open an activity when user taps on them. I have been looking for content all over internet but can't really understand how to do both task. I am using a broadcast receiver and here's my code

```
    Notification.Builder builder = new Notification.Builder(getActivity());
    builder.setContentTitle("Remember to return");
    builder.setContentText(title);
    builder.setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_notification);
    builder.setAutoCancel(true);

    //NotificationCompat.Builder builder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(getActivity());

    Notification notification = builder.build();

    Intent notificationIntent = new Intent(getActivity(),NotificationPublisher.class);

    notificationIntent.putExtra(NotificationPublisher.NOTIFICATION_ID,1);
    notificationIntent.putExtra(NotificationPublisher.NOTIFICATION,notification);

    PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(activity,0,notificationIntent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);


    //long _notificationTimeInMillis = SystemClock.elapsedRealtime()+date.getTime()+getMillisFromHours(6);
    long notificationTimeInMillis = SystemClock.elapsedRealtime() + 5000;
    AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager)activity.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
    alarmManager.set(AlarmManager.ELAPSED_REALTIME_WAKEUP,notificationTimeInMillis,pendingIntent);
    Toast.makeText(activity,"Notification Set",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
```

and for reciever

```
public class NotificationPublisher extends BroadcastReceiver {

    public static String NOTIFICATION_ID = "notification-id";
    public static String NOTIFICATION = "notification";
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

        NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager)
                context.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

        Notification notification = intent.getParcelableExtra(NOTIFICATION);
        int id = intent.getIntExtra(NOTIFICATION_ID, 0);
        notificationManager.notify(id, notification);
    }
}
```

Currently I am able to show notifications, what changes to I have to make so that an activity (say `HomeActivity.class`) opens when user clicks on notification.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to set a pending intent on the notification itself that will open the activity:

```
Notification.Builder builder = new Notification.Builder(getActivity());
builder.setContentTitle("Remember to return");
builder.setContentText(title);
builder.setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_notification);
builder.setAutoCancel(true);

// add these lines
PendingIntent pi = PendingIntent.getActivity(
    getActivity(),
    REQUEST_CODE_FOR_THIS_ONE,
    new Intent(getActivity(), HomeActivity.class),
    0
);
builder.setContentIntent(pi);

Notification notification = builder.build();
```

Comment: is flag parameter missing ? in Call to PendingIntent.getActivity() ??